# JVM crashes with OutOfMemoryError

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, out-of-memory, g1gc

I get regular jvm crashes on linux server with jdk 1.8 u121 and CPU load 100%.

VM params are

```
-XX:+UseG1GC 
-XX:+UseLargePages
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch 
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16777216 
-XX:InitialHeapSize=17179869184 
-XX:MaxHeapSize=17179869184 
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1073741824 
-XX:MetaspaceSize=1073741824 

-XX:+PrintGC 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 

-XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

GC log shows, that heap and metaspace are good garbage-collected. Full GC happens only 6 times in 2 days.

All **hs_err_pid** files say

```
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:273), pid=blabla, tid=0x0000blablabla
```

The last messages in **hs_err_pid** files from 6 lates crashes

```
Memory: 4k page, physical 24478968k(135672k free), swap 4193276k(4167448k free)

Memory: 4k page, physical 24478968k(622028k free), swap 4193276k(4168912k free)

Memory: 4k page, physical 24478968k(562104k free), swap 4193276k(4180084k free)

Memory: 4k page, physical 24478968k(365528k free), swap 4193276k(4180096k free)

Memory: 4k page, physical 24478968k(526376k free), swap 4193276k(4180108k free)

Memory: 4k page, physical 24478968k(133264k free), swap 4193276k(4179064k free)
```

What may cause this crashes? What happens to jvm? May it depend on low free physical memory?

Comment: Insufficient information. Attach a hs_err_pid file to your question.

Comment: Without a heapdump, this is impossible to analyze.

Comment: @DominikSandjaja heap is almost empty, Only 2GB from 17GB in use. What do you want to find there?

Comment: Not sure as I am not sure what to look for yet, so that is why I was asking about it :-) Is the instance running on bare metal or docker?

Comment: @DominikSandjaja, no docker